Vercel serverless function logs reporting errors from a different function. Why is this happening?
For simplicity, I have an API A, B, C, D....J. All of these endpoints simply execute read queries on firestore. I also have a write API W. All of these APIs are deployed as serverless functions in vercel with NextJS 14. As far as I know, there is no shared global state in code for them. Firestore has a deadline exceeded error which it throws while writing documents to db. This is very common with API W. However, looking at the logs, I can see errors reported in A,B,C..etc which include API w in the stack.
`Error adding document: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 109.873s,name resolution: 0.001s,metadata filters: 0.022s,LB pick: 0.003s,remote_addr=1.95:443
    at callErrorFromStatus (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:193:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:129:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:161:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@grpc+grpc-js@1.10.8/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@google-cloud+firestore@7.7.0/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:242:29
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at repeat (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:119:13
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
    at NormalApiCaller.call (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
    at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/google-gax@4.3.3/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:112:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@google-cloud+firestore@7.7.0/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:433:23)
    at DocumentReference.create (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@google-cloud+firestore@7.7.0/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:332:14)


    at CollectionReference.add (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@google-cloud+firestore@7.7.0/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2854:28)
    **at g (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/user-history/route.js:1:1716)//HERE
    at h (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/user-history/route.js:1:1863)//HERE
    at y (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/user-history/route.js:1:2107)**



    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/4483.js:1:877
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/4483.js:1:752
    at async /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.3_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:34666 {
  code: 4,
  details: 'Deadline exceeded after 109.873s,name resolution: 0.001s,metadata filters: 0.022s,LB pick: 0.003s,remote_addr=172.253.115.95:443',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}`

This is an error in API A. I have marked API W in the error stack.
How is this possible? I thought all my APIs are deployed separately and there would be no contamination of logs or error stacks between them. The only shared piece could be middleware but I have excluded all API routes from middleware so that shouldn't impact either
I went through the vercel functions doc but there is not much info on this. Nor did I see much in github issues. I excluded API routes from middleware to ensure that wasn't the issue

The error says : "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED" , perhaps its taking too long and times out ?

@easleyfixed ofcourse. However, a) if you look at the stack it is referring to user-history which is a completely different endpoint relative to where this was reported. b) The error statement starts with "Error adding documents" and the endpoint where this was reported only executes reads.
How can the stack for user-history api show up in a completely different and unrelated function?
